# Shell script cp not working (but working in terminal) Mac os X

Tags: macos, bash, shell, syntax-error, cp

I've been recently learning about shell scripting, and am stumped by a weird error:

My simple script (test.command):

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
cd /Users/Stan/Desktop/testFolder
ls 
cp "earth.png lol.png"
read -p "Done, press ENTER to finish"
```

Whenever I run the script (double clicking the .command file), here is the output (copied from terminal window):

```
earth.png
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
Copy was done...?
earth.png
Done, press ENTER to finish
```

The cp ALWAYS gives a 'usage' error, and WONT copy anything, but now if i manually run the SAME exact commands, in order in terminal (copy of terminal window):

```
Stans-Mac-mini:testFolder Stan$ ls
earth.png
Stans-Mac-mini:testFolder Stan$ cp earth.png lol.png
Stans-Mac-mini:testFolder Stan$ ls
earth.png   lol.png
Stans-Mac-mini:testFolder Stan$
```

The file got copied without any error! Please help me fix this, I couldn't find any solutions online, help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to be self-consistent.  In the script, you use double quotes; on the command line, you don't.  You get different results because of that inconsistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you quote both the source and the destination arguments provided to `cp` as one string, it only gets the one argument.

The command:

```
cp "earth.png lol.png"
```

attempts to copy one file with the name `"earth.png lol.png"` (which by the way is a perfectly valid file name), but then fails to provide a second argument.

Instead, quote each individual argument:

```
cp "earth.png" "lol.png"
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `cp` command

```
cp "earth.png" "lol.png"
```

`cp` command format is : `cp <from> <to>`. Your command has it like `cp "<single-file>"`. Both `earth.png` and `lol.png` are within the quotes and that makes it a single file. Second argument is missing and thats the reason for "usage error"